# images,sdcard,android

Tags: android, image, directory, sd-card

I want to write code to display the images only from a particular 
folder in sdcard. e.g a folder named (/sdcard/folder/). 
I have the following code, but it displays all the images in the 
sdcard. What should I add/change in the following code to accompalish 
my objective.

Should I change the query.If yes how should I change change it.

Please help me.
Thanks

`

```
      String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
      imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null,null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");
      image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
      count = imagecursor.getCount(); 
      imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
      imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
      imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,int position, long id) {
                  System.gc();
                  String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                  actualimagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,null, null, null);
                  actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                  actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                  String i = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
                  System.gc();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
                  intent.putExtra("filename", i);
                  startActivity(intent);
            }
      });
`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null,null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");
```

On above line, you are just passing you Sd card path(`MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`). I will suggest to create the variable for your path(card/newfolder/) and pass that to managedQuery

Try the answer posted in this question here [Using ImageGallery to display images from the SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415789/using-imagegallery-to-display-images-from-the-sd-card)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I created a variable path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/folder";.How should I write the query now?.Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Is your path of type Uri? If yes, just substitute that in managedQuery method.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException at this line  image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File("/sdcard/images/");
File[] allFiles = folder.list();
//allFiles array contains the files in that folder
```

Parse the files and get what you want.